# Items going through blocks while farming

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I know similar questions have been asked before, but I haven’t gotten any answers.

I am in a creative world making a basalt generator on Minecraft Bedrock. The prototype works, but some of the basalt is going through the glass. I have an extra layer on top, but it’s still goes through. The farm works by having the basalt generate and then I mine it with an Efficiency 5 pickaxe.

Should I use a slower pickaxe? Should I use a different block other than glass?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a screenshot detailing the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you add a screenshot, or add more details?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this: Your item entities are probably flying through the corners of glass blocks:

```
G = Glass block
X = Missing blocks
```

```
X G X
G   G
X G X
```

There is a simple fix: Add glass blocks to fill in the corners. However, this will prevent you from picking items up. It would be advised to place a hopper minecart under the soul soil.